# Why was Neo's body let go from the machine's farm?

Tags: the-matrix

- The dead/malfunctioning humans are liquified and feed intravenously to active humans in the Matrix. Why was Neo let go, when he is freed and his body falls into a river before being rescued by Morpheus' crew?
- The Nebuchadnezzar physically went to the river, which is adjacent to the machine's human bio farm, to rescue Neo. Why didn't the Sentinels attack them? Isn't there any security?

Comment: I think each bullet point could be a separate question.

Comment: ...and check for duplicates before doing so. I'd imagine these have been asked before.

Answer (score 4):

> Why was Neo let go?

**Because it's part of the plan.**

We know the Matrix is a system of control.  We find out in *The Matrix Reloaded* (when Neo speaks to the Architect) that Zion, the resistance and the One are also part of the system of control (created by the Oracle) to account for the percentage who will not properly accept the programming of the Matrix.

The idea is the resistance builds and the One is found.  Then the sentinels attack Zion, the One goes to the Source with the survivors and we rinse and repeat.

The clues to things being different this time show when Smith starts going off script (the Morpheus interrogation where he takes off earpiece and shades).  This results in the escalation in Smith's and Neo's powers as the Matrix tries to balance each other out.

When Morpheus finds potential "Ones", the system knows this, and the agents/sentinels are really only there to create an false narrative of fight to keep the resistance misled.

The system already knows who Neo is, and had tried the 'Gestapo crap' by the time Morpheus extracts him (and indeed that is to encourage him to go with Morpheus,  although Smith etc aren't aware of the ramifications).

They could have killed Neo as he woke and stopped the whole cycle, but **it is the machines' plan** for Neo to be extracted so they don't make too much of an effort.

It's all a dance, if they really wanted to destroy all the resistance they could hit Zion prior to the latest One being found (they've done it 5 times already), the whole thing is just part of the system of control.

This also is part of the self-determination discussions between Neo and the Oracle.  What Neo discovers in *Reloaded* is that his "making his own fate" as Neo is as much part of the script as his life as Mr Anderson was.

He only truly changes things when he goes through the "wrong" door to save Trinity.

Consider also that they mention they don't know the real year, and that people are usually extracted at a young age, and Morpheus has spent his 'entire life' searching for Neo.  So the machines will likely encourage the hunt as the reset may take decades (of peace for the system) before the hunt for the One reaches the stage we see in *The Matrix*

Comment: I would contend that there was no "wrong" or "right" door. It was all part of the illusion of choice that had to be provided to create cycles of stability. Either door was going to lead to a "reload". The "source" door led to an immediate reload and the 2nd door led to a subsequent reload. Both provided the illusion that The One had made a choice.

Comment: Well I was deliberate in saying "wrong" in quotes.  Neo still chose a different path from the previous Ones, and the outcome, although still leading to a reload, ended with a different result regarding the state of human/machine relations, so thing did change.  But remember the more things change, the more they stay the same (as the saying goes).

Comment: Agreed, there was _a_ change. But I have to wonder how significant it was. I think we could play the Architect and Oracle's final conversation **before** the first Matrix and it would still be just as valid as it was at the **end** of Revelations: "You played a very dangerous game." "Change always is." "Just how long do you think this piece will last?" "As long as it can." "What about the others?" "What others?" "The ones that want out." "Obviously they will be freed." "I have your word?" "What do you think I am? Human?"

Answer (score 0):

> Why was Neo let go?

Contamination. In the Matrix universe, human beings are grown and spend their whole life in giant pods. Those pods are perfectly sterile. What the crew of Nebuchadnezzar did was

1. put tracer into Neo
2. tracer also blocks signal from Matrix to Neo
3. tracer program also blocks signal from Neo to Matrix

Think of that whole thing from machine point of view, from caretaker's point of view.

1. The pod has malfunctioned. You go there to check what happened.
2. A human being that was housed in that pod doesn't show inside the Matrix any more. His heart and lungs might be working still, but you know whose hearts and lungs are also working for a while without consciousness? Hearts and lungs of people in comma and those who are brain dead. That is if the heart and lungs diagnostic signal is not blocked too..
3. It takes much more resources to keep a person alive which cannot breathe unassisted. Neo is not in the Matrix, therefore he is brain dead, therefore his lungs and hearts will stop working soon.
4. You check what happened. The pod is broken. Whatever happened to the pod's inhabitant, in his death throes he had broken the pod. Before housing new human being in it, it will have to be repaired and sterilized again. But more importantly, that human being for some reason had adverse reaction to SOMETHING. That something might be chemical inside his body.
5. Machines breed "docile" / domesticated humans. If Neo's "corruption" is allowed to spread, either via breeding him with other humans or via feeding his remains to other humans, whole crops might be lost in the future!
6. Best possible solution is therefore to disconnect and flush the contaminant out of the system.

> The Nebuchadnezzar physically went to the river, which is adjacent to the machine's human bio farm, to rescue Neo. Why didn't the Sentinels attack them? Isn't there any security?

Two problems with that reasoning. Consider the location and events.

1. It's a garbage dump quite a bit away from farm. You won't guard your compost heap or garbage dump as much as you would your pigsty.
2. The crew did the whole operation rather quickly.  It was quick get in, grab and run job. It is possible if they stayed for longer that sentinels or some other sort of security would have shown up. Also, they might have shown up anyway - Neo loses consciousness right after being saved from that river. The truth is, we have too little information as to what happened while he was unconscious and for how long he was unconscious.

Comment: In the Architect's speech we learn that The One and Zion are planned parts of the control system. They are essentially a garbage collection routine. Neo was let go simply because he chose to be.

Comment: That is correct. But you should remember that Neo, Trinity and Morpheus are hackers. It would be completely in character for them to use existing systems of Machines in perverted ways. Let's say there exists system in farm which is used to anesthetize pregnant women and remove them from the pod so the child can be removed and modified so it can be plugged into Matrix. Or virus infected body which should be flushed. They wrote a trojan which hijacks that system and says: "Jo1storm is infected by deadly influenza virus, dump him right now before he spreads it to other humans. DO NOT LIQUEFY."

Comment: In short, I basically answered how, you added higher WHY. Trinity, Cipher and Morpheus also passed through same procedure. In fact, it might be that machines gave Zionites those tools, those pills, which hijack farm's waste dumping procedures.